# How to hide "Save" button on the MS Dialogue (pop-up) Ribbon?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, custom-form, modal-dialog

I want to hide the "Save" button in the pop-up window which appears when we add new item.

I tried using javascript getElementById to hide in NewForm.aspx page but it didn't work.

**Update:**
 I executed the following code, but didn't work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".ms-cui-ctl-large .ms-cui-ctl-largelabel:first").text("Request");
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are giving people the option to add a list item but then denying them the ability to save it?  Is there some other process doing the save?

Comment: @DaveWise I am using the NewForm.aspx button to be "Request" not "Save". So I changed the button below. But I am not able to change the Ribbon Button "Save". Either I want to hide it or change the text to "Request"

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to hide the save button.

```
<style>
#Ribbon\.ListForm\.Edit\.Commit
    {
        display: none !important;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have jQuery included (and who doesn't these days!) it is simply a matter of executing the script below on the NewForm.aspx page after the ribbon is built.

```
jQuery(".ms-cui-ctl-large .ms-cui-ctl-largelabel:first").text("Request")
```

If you need a server-based solution, there's also [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff407619%28v=office.14%29.aspx) from Microsoft.

Comment: I have updated my question. I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You added the javascript code to newform.aspx, and not the list view page, correct?

Comment: Yes, I added the script to NewForm.aspx. Not to the list view

Comment: fwiw, I have had occasional issues using the `$` token for jQuery in SharePoint, which is why I use the full name of `jQuery(...)` instead

Comment: It didn't work as well. But I hide the commit group. Thats all I wanted. I have added my answer.